# How to integrate this form with my existing custom template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've installed Userena, and I am trying to figure out how to integrate the existing userena form with my own custom HTML form template, I have pasted part of the code for the userena form template, and I do not see ANY css or html, so I'm very confused about how I would integrate this with my own template consisting of HTML, CSS.  I figured with Django I'd be able to take any old HTML form and just plugin Django's variables to get it working.

So my question is how can I integrate the top example (userenas form template) into the bottom example (generic HTML example).  An example might be helpful.

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <legend>{% trans "Signup" %}</legend>
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {% comment %} Displaying checkboxes differently {% endcomment %}
    {% if field.name == 'tos' %}




<form action="/register/" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nameinput" placeholder="Name" name="contact-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="emailinput" placeholder="Email" name="contact-email">
    </div>
```

Comment: your question not receive well attention because it's unclear what's the question itself ..?

Comment: As far i figured out you want to add contact-name & contact-email .. Am i right ?